# How does Vue.js render page happens?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

It really scares me that I might want to know this thing so much. That's the whole essence of **SPA** (Single-Page Application). I am curious about [Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) rendering pages. I will list some of my knowledge and If I'm wrong, please correct me. Things I think I know:

- There's a which might be a tree-structure parsed from html.
- Then, [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) RENDER TREE IS constructoted from css and that DOM-TREE
- After that, rendering page means data is shown on the screen.

What about **Vue.js**? I know it has virtual DOM. If I change something with Javascript in Vue.js, the real change happens in virtual DOM because it's faster and then syncing with the real template happens. If all that is right(if wrong, please tell me) then my question is the following:

When I use [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/) and click some link to change the page, When new page gets shown, `beforeMount()` is called, then if i click back button to go the previous page, `beforeMount()` is called also. When using `Vue Router` and back button, does page rendering happens again or it's saved somewhere and to make it faster, it gets all the html from cache? So If I go to some page, then click back or `Vue Router` link, and page rendering starts from scratch, why would it be fast?

In my opinion, page rendering happens when there's some data changed or it's the first time I am accessing that specific URL. For the second time accessing, if data has not changed, it doesn't render the page from scratch. What do you think ? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if someone will answer with exact steps but best way to know that is to check the source code of vue.js.

Comment: Thanks jcubic, but I need an experienced person's answer.

Comment: Take a look at [keep-alive](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#keep-alive).